# not found: value udf error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a udf defined in my code as follows:

```
val toOriginalTimestamp = udf((timestamp: String) => timestamp.substring(0, 18))
```

I'm trying to take a substring of the timestamp field in my dataset. However I'm getting the error as not found: value udf

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you imported `udf`? Also, please use code formatting to make your question more readable.

Answer (score 11):

You probably need this one:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
```

Also, make sure that you are using spark-sql (not just spark-core!) 1.3 or higher dependencies.